# How can I do a binary search of a text file for a specific character string?

Tags: sed, awk, grep, hex

I have a text file that contains a large number of records, each on a single line. Some of the records have special characters that have been corrupted, and I'm attempting to find those by looking for multiple sequences of characters higher than `x80`

Here is a single line sample with the incorrect characters highlighted:

[image]

The hex string of interest is:

```
49 CC 80 C2 B9 6E
```

When I use GNU Grep, `grep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" record.txt` it matches only part of the line, it matches the superscript 1 (`¹`) but not the `Ì`:

[image]

Grep doesn't seem to be able to break the combined character+diacritic apart...

What I'd like to do is keep only the lines that have two or more consecutive `x80` characters - and to be able to match on actual characters that show up in the hex code - i.e. `49 CC 80 C2 B9 6E` seems like it should match something like `"[\x80-\xFF]{2,10}"` - but this matching does not work.

So, to clarify, when I use this, the line matches:

```
grep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" record.txt
```

But when I use this, it does not:

```
grep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]{2,10}" record.txt
```

Shouldn't the second one match, too, since the sequence of bytes is `CC 80 C2 B9` which is a string of 4 consecutive bytes with the values of `x80-xFF`?

Comment: That regex should match lines containing any high bit characters, though I do not know what "part of the line" means, as `grep` probably isn't doing anything fancy with encoding. `perl -C0 -nle 'print if m/[\x80-\xFF]{2,10}/'` appears to match as well, though I only reproduced a subset of your hard-to-copy screenshot for testing.

Comment: Thanks @thrig. I agree - the screenshot was not ideal - but wasn't sure the best way to share the sample lines without having the characters further scrambled - thoughts?

Comment: The raw data could be shared as the output of e.g. `xxd` or `hexdump`, which in the case of `xxd` can then have `xxd -r` run on it to reverse it back to binary.

Comment: "binary search" has a meaning in computer science. :)

Answer (score 3):

This could be locale related. If so, using the C (aka POSIX) locale, where characters are bytes, may work:

```
LC_ALL=C grep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]{2,10}" record.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Grep can be wonky with odd characters..  try:

```
grep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" record.txt |  iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-16
```

It might get your letters back..  but your colors will be lost.
Might be worth mucking with the utf-16 and utf-8.

And make sure your console is able to handle uft-8, and isn't assigned to some ansi setting.

Comment: How can I add in the `{2,10}` piece to specify that I want to match only when there are 2-10 characters in the `x80-xFF` range? I updated my question to clarify.